# Autowiring all beans of generic class

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, autowired

I have the following class hierarchy:

```
public class Base {}
public class A extends Base {}
public class B extends Base {}

public class MyClassDefinition<T extends Base>  {}
```

Then I am creating couple beans of `MyClassDefinition` in a `@Configuration` class:

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public MyClassDefinition<A> aMyClassDefinition {
        return new MyClassDefinition<A>();
    }

    @Bean
    public MyClassDefinition<B> aMyClassDefinition {
        return new MyClassDefinition<B>();
    }
}
```

Now I need to get a list of all `MyClassDefinition<T extends Base>` beans:

```
public class SomeClass {

    @Autowired
    private Map<String, MyClassDefinition<Base>> definitions;

}
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work and an exception is thrown:

```
No qualifying bean of type 'java.util.Map<String, MyClassDefinition<Base>>' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

Any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: Note that neither of your classes meets that requirement; you need `MyClassDefinition<? extends Base>`.

Comment: @chrylis Ohh, you are completely right. I don't know how could I miss that. Thank you!